# Reading my trace through DDMS method-profiling (DEBUGGING ANR's)

Tags: android, performance, profiling, trace, ddms

## THE ISSUE

So my Android application freezes/unresponsive (I get ANR if screen is touched) right after 15 minutes pass. The application is meant to stay awake and not lock due to it being used for customers who want to use it throughout the day. However, it stops working after 15 minutes, a very specific set of time, which makes it highly unusual. My memory usage is good, only using about 3%  memory from the device and CPU load only using 14% for my app.

I researched ANR's and found that it is caused from UI blocking, so I opened DDMS and started method-profiling when the app ran. The picture below is what I see.

[image]

with the method being called in the yellow, **Process Manager** (see below)

[image]

The other red method that my cursor is on is the String method but I don't know if this is a big issue since it only lasts for about 1 ms.

### MY QUESTION

At about every 250 ms, the trace repeats itself, and the process manager method I guess blocks the UI thread for some time with some garbage collecter time in the middle of it executing. See below picture.
[image]

I believe this is my problem, but I have no clue on where the process manager is executing my line of code. Any thoughts? I'm new to using this method-profiling tool. ***My only guess is that its looking external SD cards to mount?*** See debug picture!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I found out from the debugger view and the trace, that process manager was blocking the UI thread. From the debug view, the main thread **STOPPED** running after being called by my runnable CheckExternalSdRunnable that ran for about 9 msec ***EVERY*** 250 msec. I guess this bogged down performance and input events could not be handled. I commented out this one line of code that called the runnable, and sure enough it has been running for about a day now.

I re-opened method-profiling and sure enough, that runnable running on the main thread was gone, which showed hardly no UI-blocking whatsoever! That one line of code got rid of mostly all other smaller processes that blocked the UI-thread for a short period of time.

*Anyone else having the same issue should open the debugger while viewing the method-profiling option under the DDMS and look for processes that block UI and then use the debugger to view the main thread and see what piece of code code was called that caused the application to display a ANR*